# Changing images on Button press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code that changes multiple images on my website. Right now I can change the images once but I can not change them back to the original images. I was trying to use .toggle after my .css to change the images back and fourth but that did not work. How would I go about solving this?

```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("#secriuty").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/secriuty-fundamentals-certificate.png')"}), 
      $("#js").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/js-certificate.png')"}),
      $("#html5").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/html5-certificate.png')"}),
      $("#html-css").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/html-and-css-certificate.png')"}),
      $("#photoshop").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/photoshop-certificate.png')"}),
      $("#illustrator").css({"background-image": "url('images/certificates/illustrator-certificate.png')"})
    });
```

Comment: One way would be to move your background-image changes to a CSS class and use `.toggleClass` instead of inlining the CSS. e.g. `$("#illustrator").toggleClass("newpic");`

Comment: I have already tried that and here is what it looks like $("button").click(function(){
  $("#secriuty").toggleClass("#secriuty-color"), 
  $("#js").toggleClass("#js-color"),
  $("#html5").toggleClass("#html5-color"),
  $("#html-css").toggleClass("#html-css-color"),
  $("#photoshop").toggleClass("#photoshop-color"),
  $("#illustrator").toggleClass("#illustrator-color")
}); This code however does not work it never changes the images.

Comment: @AlexanderMurdock check my answer, you can use a checkbox to toggle the background image.

Comment: @AlexanderMurdock `#security-color` is an ID -- not a class -- it should be `.toggleClass("security-color")` and `.security-color { css changes}` and expecting the code to update to `<div id="security" class="security-color"></div>`

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$('.checkbox').click(function() {

  const button = $(this).parent('#button');
  
  if( $(button).find('.checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
    $("#aaa").css({"background-image": "url('https://picsum.photos/id/141/150/150')"}) 
    $("#bbb").css({"background-image": "url('https://picsum.photos/id/222/150/150')"})
    $("#ccc").css({"background-image": "url('https://picsum.photos/id/27/150/150')"})
  } else {
    $(".div").css({"background-image": ""})
  }

})
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/121/150/150');
}
#bbb {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/121/150/150');
}
#ccc {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/121/150/150');
}
.div {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.div:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
/* Button */
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div id="aaa" class="div"></div>
  <div id="bbb" class="div"></div>
  <div id="ccc" class="div"></div>
</div>
<div id="button" class="btn">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
  <span>Change Background</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.toggleClass`:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#security").toggleClass("newpic");
});
```

```css
#security {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
}
#security.newpic {
  background: url("http://www.fillmurray.com/300/253");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="security"></div>
<button>Click me</button>
```